# Extracting string between ' '

Tags: string, parsing, char, extract

Good day, I'm struggling to find code to parse a character and achieve only what lies between the ' '. In this case I have:

```
Char Character = "'2'; 0x32"
```

Here I'd like to only extract the 2 from the string and save it to another variable.  If anyone can provide me with code to do such it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can write this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>  // for sscanf
int main()
{
  // your string
  const char *text = "'2'; 0x32";

  // your variable
  int variable;

  // a working variable, to be set to the number of characters matched by sscanf
  int used;

  // match the patter on a single quote followed by an integer
  // if that integer is found, its value will be written to `variable`
  // then write the used characters into `used` working variable
  // the result from the function is 1, when the variable was found
  if (sscanf(text, "'%d%n", &variable, &used) != 1)
  {
    // explain to the user that there is a syntax error
    printf("Invalid input: expecting \"^'[0-9]+'(.*)\"");

    // exit with an error
    return 1;
  }

  // confirm that after the integer there is a single quote
  if (text[used] != '\'')
  {
    // explain to the user that there is a syntax error
    printf("An integer was found, but no trailing single quote exists.");

    // exit with an error
    return 2;
  }

  // success
  printf("The integer enclosed in the single quotes is %d", variable);

  // exit without errors
  return 0;
}
```